# Reverse Engineer Struct from Binary Array Examples

Tags: arrays, struct, reverse-engineering

Are there any tools for statistical analysis or reverse engineering of struct definitions when given multiple raw byte array contents as examples? I'm trying to reverse engineer a variable-length struct for which I have thousands of example records. Before beginning writing my own tool, are there any existing tools?

E.g., "bytes x through y always fall in the ASCII range", or "byte x is always one of two values", "byte y always seems Boolean (`0x0` or `0x1`)", etc.

Context: I'm trying to reverse engineer the "IsInstalled" column of the Windows Update `Datastore.edb` file.

Comment: How do you have a variable-length struct? I'm pretty sure that anything that's variable-length is, in fact, a pointer, but then it's really the pointer that's stored in the struct, not the data.

Comment: Presumably there are subtypes depending on some indicator, though that hadn't occurred to me before, silly mistake on my part. Regardless, all I know is have thousands of data-points of various lengths, all representing the same _type_ of data.

Comment: I already know the data is not ASCII or Unicode. I expected the data to be Boolean (the column is titled "IsInstalled"), but the field is a byte array between 10-50ish bytes.